# How to improve performance of uploading heavy images to server

Tags: android, image, performance, api, image-processing

I'm sending multiple image to server using my Android mobile app.

Our business requirements are to have the best quality images and have them as big as possible and this starts a pretty big mess.

Single image take from 3-5 MB size. I've to do 4-5 requests (send 4-5 images).

When I start to do API requests, it usually does not do anything for around 15-30 seconds..

[image]

It feels like a timeout.. and then after those 15-30 seconds, images are actually sent pretty fast (if we don't count the timeout):

[image]

I call requests like this:

```
private fun sendImagesToServer() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(dispatcherProvider.background) {

            Images.forEach { img ->
                val sessionImageFile = File(img.FilePath)

                ApiClient.getInstance().sendImage(
                    sessionImageFile
                ) { response ->
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        ...
                    } else {
                        Timber.i("Image WAS NOT sent successfully: ")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the actual request implementation looks like this:

```
 public void sendImage(
    File imageFile,
    ServiceCallback<ServiceResponse<Void>> callback
) {
    /* Preparing header data */
    HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
    headerMap.put("X-IMS-xxx", ..);
    headerMap.put("X-IMS-aaa", ..);
    headerMap.put("X-IMS-ccc", ..);
    headerMap.put("X-IMS-bb", "...");

    /* Parsing image */
    MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
        "file",
        imageFile.getName(),
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),
        imageFile)
    );

    ClientCore.sendPicture(
        filePart,
        headerMap,
        callback
    );
}

@Multipart
@Headers("..: true")
@POST("...")
Call<Session> sendPicture(
    @Part MultipartBody.Part filePart,
    @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers
);
```

I tried to upload all the images using web app and it took 16 seconds for all images - which is fine. Mobile app also uploads images around the same time, but the problem is the timeout before it actually start to upload. What is causing this and how to avoid it?

I did test this same implementation with compressed images that had size of 200-300 KBs, it worked pretty fast, but I'm trying to find a solution to follow business requirements here.

Is this normal behaviour? How to improve performance of this task?

**UPDATE:**

```
2019-10-02 10:34:07.493 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: ===== Detect pool-thread leak =====
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Executors.java:569)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: sxq.newThread(Unknown Source:9)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1393)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: sru.a(:com.google.android.gms@19419039@19.4.19 (100408-269184076):14)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: sru.execute(:com.google.android.gms@19419039@19.4.19 (100408-269184076):2)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: sfs.a(:com.google.android.gms@19419039@19.4.19 (100408-269184076):2)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: scg.a(:com.google.android.gms@19419039@19.4.19 (100408-269184076):28)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: sez.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@19419039@19.4.19 (100408-269184076):36)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:675)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: aaht.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@19419039@19.4.19 (100408-269184076):18)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:675)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: dxz.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@19419039@19.4.19 (100408-269184076):3)
2019-10-02 10:34:07.494 21705-21732/? E/rs$DefaultThreadFactory: android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
```

Comment: If you really fill the problem with timeout then increase it at both server and client side.

Comment: @MD I actually want to avoid time-outs at all costs and just do the image upload asap. Updated: Added extra logs. looks like thread is leaking.

Comment: @MaartinAndroid 
How did you resolve this?. I am interested in the compression part for multiple images. A repository or example will be of help

Comment: @MaartinAndroid Did you find the solution for this error log?